Use added tokens in BertTokenizer with a BartForConditionalGeneration model
I have a BertTokenizer and I added some tokens to it.
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("raptorkwok/wordseg-tokenizer")
print(len(tokenizer)) # 245289
print(tokenizer.vocab_size) # 51271

The 51,271 vocabs are in vocab.txt, while the added tokens are in added_tokens.json. If I want to make use of these new tokens in a model, e.g. BartForConditionalGeneration, how can I apply these new tokens in the model?
For example, I called the model with the codes:
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("fnlp/bart-base-chinese")
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

The model has a new size of 245,289.
What is my next step in letting the model adopt the new tokens? should I re-train the model?

Yes, you should. All the new tokens have randomly initialized weights and your model will only produce garbage now because it can handle them properly.

But how to re-train the BartForConditionalGeneration model?

You could follow a traditional seq2seq training objective or the one that was used for BART originally. Depending on how much compute you have and how much time you want to invest, you could try to freeze the/some attention layers. But the embedding layers need to be trainable!

Thanks. Could you share some links so that I can study? I'm stuck right now.

Some pretraining scripts/options are listed here.

Pretraining scripts ignored the newly added tokens. Please refer to this new question. Thanks.
